Auto-Incrementation of custom ID numbers for new entries in an ArcGIS Survey123 Form?
ArcGIS Survey123 is being used as a Public Data Entry tool that exports PDF reports.  As part of the process, it is required that auto-incremented ID #'s are assigned to new entries.
The form is set up to:

Pull the highest ID # and store it in a field, using:
"pulldata("@layer", "getValue", "attributes.permitID", ${devAppService}, "1=1")"

Enter the next # in sequence in a new field, using:
"if(string-length(${permitIDData}) = 0, 1,  if(string-length(${permitIDData}) = 7, number(substr(${permitIDData}, 5, 7)) + 1, number(substr(${permitIDData}, 4, 6)) +1))"

Select the correct prefix, based on the type of survey entry (i.e., application type) and store it in a field.

Concatenate the Prefix (Step 3) and the next # (Step 2) to in the final ID field, using:
"if(string-length(${permitIDInt}) = 1, concat(${permitPrefix}, format-date(now(), '%y'), '0', number(${permitIDInt})), concat(${permitPrefix}, format-date(now(), '%y'), number(${permitIDInt})))"


The form works, however it does not work correctly.  It will create the new ID # in sequence, but for some reason it skipped a whole series of numbers, and continued the sequence from that point.
I have reached out to Tech Support and the response received is that Survey123 does not directly support auto-incrementation and I was provided & reviewed the information available here: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/auto-increment-integer-using-survey123/td-p/816815.  I have also reviewed the information available here: Creating automatic unique ID in Survey123 for ArcGIS?. However, I cannot seem to resolve the issue or come up with another solution.
Is there any way to customize or correct this functionality to correctly work in Survey123?
